When does a weak reference from threadlocal take effect?
public class BaseContext {

    public static ThreadLocal<Long> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setCurrentId(Long id) {
        threadLocal.set(id);
    }

    public static Long getCurrentId() {
        return threadLocal.get();
    }

    public static void removeCurrentId() {
        threadLocal.remove();
    }


}

I created such a threadlocal utility class to store the ID of the user. I use this class in the interceptor every time I receive an http request. I checked the document and found that the weak reference to threadlocal in threadlocalmap is for the GC to reclaim threadlocal when the external strong reference to threadlocal disappears, making the key in entry null. Entries with null keys will be removed in the next set, get, and remove.
My problem is that my utility class never seems to lose a strong reference to threadlocal, so a weak reference seems to lose its meaning. Under what circumstances does such a weak reference mechanism work? Is threadlocal defined somewhere else?

If you never eliminate the reference to threadLocal (by setting threadLocal = null, for example), then nothing will ever get collected.

Thank you for the reply. I will call the remove method after the interceptor processes the request, which should be sufficient. However, I doubt many people would write threadlocal = null like this, so I am curious about when weak references take effect. Perhaps sometimes threadlocal is a local variable, and the mechanism of weak references kicks in after losing the strong reference?

Correct; this is about when it's used as a local variable.

The ThreadLocal object itself won't be GC'd until this static reference is cleared (at least), but each per-thread map it implicitly contains will become eligible for GC when the thread for which it was created exits and all references to it arte lost.

Even references in static variables may become unreachable, that is, when the class was loaded by a custom class loader and the class loader (and all classes defined by it) becomes unreachable. Such code unloading is optional, but the HotSpot JVM supports it (unless turned off with a startup option). That case, as well as the scenario of a thread local in a non-static variable, might look like corner cases, but the Java standard library has to work correctly, even in corner cases.

ThreadLocal's usage of WeakReference means that it will be deleted despite references in threads that use this ThreadLocal. That also means that after a Thread dies any values related to it in ThreadLocal will be GC-ed.
